# Basic animation not performing

Tags: java, swing, animation

I am learning java. This is my first animation. I want a ball to move up and down continuously  when start button is pressed, and it should  `STOP` when stop button is pressed. The code I have written moves the ball 5 times(3 times down and 2 times up). But the panel displays only start and final positions, it does not display intermediate positions. How to display intermediate positions as well?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class dabble
{
    private boolean z = true;
    private int x=10;
    private int y=10;
    private JFrame frame;
    private JLabel label;
    private mypanel panel;
    private JButton b1;
    private JButton b2;

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        dabble dab = new dabble();
        dab.start();
    }

    void start()
    {
        frame = new JFrame();
        label = new JLabel();
        panel = new mypanel();
        b1= new JButton("Start");
        b2= new JButton("Stop");

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        b1.addActionListener(new al1());
        b2.addActionListener(new al2());

        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.NORTH,b1);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH,b2);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER,panel);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.EAST,label);
        frame.setSize(600,600);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    void go()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            if(z==false)
                break;
            //label.setText("Hi");
            y=510-y;
            panel.repaint();
            try{
                Thread.sleep(500);
                //label.setText("sleep");
            }catch(Exception Ex)
            {
             //label.setText("exp");
            }
        }
    }

    class al1 implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
            go();
        }
    }

    class al2 implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
            z=false;
        }
    }

    class mypanel extends JPanel 
    {
        public void paintComponent ( Graphics g)
        {
            g.setColor(Color.white);
            g.fillRect(0,0,this.getWidth(),this.getHeight());
            int red = (int) (Math.random()*255);
            int green = (int) (Math.random()*255);
            int blue = (int) (Math.random()*255);
            Color c1 = new Color(red,green,blue);
            g.setColor(c1);
            g.fillOval(x,y,20,20);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ever considered indenting your code?

Comment: You should learn "How to write code?". Learn coding style, naming convention and follow them.

Comment: I regret the bad code writing, @Ademiban thanks

Answer (score 2):

Calling `repaint()` does not actually paint the panel - it just marks it to be painted later. And painting always happens on the event dispatch thread, as do event listener notifications.

Since `go()` is being called on the event dispatch thread (by a button action listener), the panel cannot be repainted while `go()` is running. You simply queue up a single repaint that happens as soon as `go()` is done.

What you probably want to do is to use a `javax.swing.Timer` that fires once every 500 ms, and have its action be to move the ball one step and then call `repaint()`.

Answer (score 0):

Well you perform your loop 5 times (instead of an infinite loop). Moreover you change the vertical position from 10 to 500 and then back to 10 etc... If you want to see intermediate position, you should consider asking to repaint the intermediate positions as well providing the intermediate values of y.

OK, doing the following solves your issues but it is definitely a poor design:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class dabble {

    private static final long ANIMATION_DURATION = 5000; // 5 seconds
    private static final int REFRESH_RATE = 10;// 10 times per second
    private boolean incrementing = true;
    private volatile boolean z = true;
    private int x = 10;
    private volatile int y = 10;
    private JFrame frame;
    private JLabel label;
    private mypanel panel;
    private JButton b1;
    private JButton b2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        dabble dab = new dabble();
        dab.start();
    }

    void start() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        label = new JLabel();
        panel = new mypanel();
        b1 = new JButton("Start");
        b2 = new JButton("Stop");

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        b1.addActionListener(new al1());
        b2.addActionListener(new al2());

        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.NORTH, b1);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, b2);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, panel);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.EAST, label);
        frame.setSize(600, 600);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    void go() {
        new Animation().start();
    }

    class al1 implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            go();
        }
    }

    class al2 implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            z = false;
        }
    }

    class mypanel extends JPanel {
        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(Color.white);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
            int red = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
            int green = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
            int blue = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
            Color c1 = new Color(red, green, blue);
            g.setColor(c1);
            g.fillOval(x, y, 20, 20);
        }
    }

    class Animation extends Thread {

        private long start;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            while (true) {
                if (!z) {
                    return;
                }
                double progress = (double) (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) / ANIMATION_DURATION;
                System.err.println(progress);
                if (incrementing) {
                    y = (int) (10 + 500 * progress);
                } else {
                    y = (int) (510 - 500 * progress);
                }
                if (progress > 1.0) {
                    start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    incrementing = !incrementing;
                }

                panel.repaint();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000 / REFRESH_RATE);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree that I am performing it 5 times only, but it should display those 5 positions. It is showing the final position only.

Comment: Well, you are invoking repaint() which basically puts a RepaintEvent request in the AWT-Event queue, so this will be done once you have released the current thread. Instead, you call sleep in the AWT-Event queue which prevents event from being dispatch (including the repaint event), therefore, you have a single repaint (repaint events are merged together) that happens at the end of your loop. You should rather have a separate `Thread` invoking `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() { public void run() { repaint();}});` and then sleep 500 ms.

Comment: Actually, if it's in a separate thread you can just call `repaint()` directly (this is one of the few Swing methods that is safe for non-EDT use).

Comment: You're right, repaint() automatically post the event in the event queue so the repaint() can be safely called oustide the AWT thread.

Comment: Disclaimer: I'm near thread-agnostic, so just wondering :-) Definitly true that repaint can be called from any thread - but is it safe to access x and y from different threads?

Comment: with the volatile keyword, yes. and since there is only a single thread writing to it, yes again.

Comment: ahh .. missed the volatile (could be because x isn't :-) Thanks

Comment: @RussellZahniser thanks,  i implemented repaint method on the new thread. It works, what all swing methods can be called safely from non-EDT thread ?

Comment: @JohnWatson: You can add and remove listeners (which doesn't affect any event dispatch in progress), and call `repaint()` and `revalidate()`. It is also OK to construct your GUI in a background thread, as long as you don't touch it after it becomes displayable. See [this link](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/performance/1st_edition/html/JPSwingThreads.fm.html#1001870).